# C# regular expression to find custom markers and take content

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
productDescription
```

In it are some custom tags such as:

```
[MM][/MM]
```

For example the string might read:

> This product is [MM]1000[/MM] long

Using a regular expression how can I find those MM tags, take the content of them and replace everything with another string?  So for example the output should be:

> This product is 10 cm long

Comment: I think this will require more than just a regex. What should `[M]1000[/M]` render? `1km`?

Comment: I'm fine writing all the conversion stuff, just need to work out how to actually take the content of the tag and replace it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll need to pass a delegate to the regex for that.

```
Regex theRegex = new Regex(@"\[MM\](\d+)\[/MM\]");
text = theRegex.Replace(text, delegate(Match thisMatch)
{

    int mmLength = Convert.ToInt32(thisMatch.Groups[1].Value);
    int cmLength = mmLength / 10;
    return cmLength.ToString() + "cm";
});
```

Comment: Awesome.  I never knew there was a version of Regex.Replace which took a delegate.

Comment: A bit more modern syntax would be `match => { /*...*/ return "something"; }`, or simply passing a named method.

Answer (score 1):

Using [RegexDesigner.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sayanghosh/regex-designer-feel-the-raw-power-of-regex):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// Regex Replace code for C#
void ReplaceRegex()
{
    // Regex search and replace
    RegexOptions   options = RegexOptions.None;
    Regex          regex = new Regex(@"\[MM\](?<value>.*)\[\/MM\]", options);
    string         input = @"[MM]1000[/MM]";
    string         replacement = @"10 cm";
    string         result = regex.Replace(input, replacement);

    // TODO: Do something with result
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(result, "Replace");
}
```

Or if you want the orginal text back in the replacement:

```
Regex          regex = new Regex(@"\[MM\](?<theText>.*)\[\/MM\]", options);
string         replacement = @"${theText} cm";
```

Comment: Thanks!  Out of curiosity what does the @ symbole signify?

Comment: Also I need to take the value inbetween the tags, how do I do this?  Your example is hardcoded for my example

Comment: it means that the compiler doesn't try to translate the string using escape sequences such as \r \n etc.

Comment: @Tom - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx - it's a 'verbatim string', where the \ chars don't act as escapes.

Answer (score 0):

A regex like this

```
\[(\w+)\](\d+)\[\/\w+\]
```

will find and collect the units (like MM) and the values (like 1000).  That would at least allow you to use the pairs of parts intelligently to do the conversion.  You could then put the replacement string together, and do a straightforward string replacement, because you know the exact string you're replacing.

I don't think you can do a simple RegEx.Replace, because you don't know the replacement string at the point you do the search.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Regex rex = new Regex(@"\[MM\]([0-9]+)\[\/MM\]");

    string s = "This product is [MM]1000[/MM] long";

    MatchCollection mc = rex.Matches(s);
```

Will match only integers.

```
    mc[n].Groups[1].Value;
```

will then give the numeric part of nth match.